# How to compile module scss in vue component? (laravel-mix)

Tags: vue.js, sass, laravel-mix, css-modules

> I tried to configure the webpack file in laravel project. And faced with situation when without ***lang="scss"*** attribute modular css works fine, but I need work with SCSS. I can’t understand what I need to do to compile modular scss.
>   How I can configure this?

**Webpack config:**

```
 module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                loaders: [
                    {
                        loader: 'css-loader',
                        options: {
                            modules: true,
                            localIdentName: '[local]_[hash:base64:8]',
                        },
                    },
                ],
            },
        ],
    },
```

**Vue component:**

```
<div :id="$style['requests-container']"...

<style lang="scss" scoped module>
#requests-container {
    z-index: 10000;
    position: fixed;
    min-width: 100px;
    top: 50px;
    left: 50%;
    padding: 10px;
    background-image: linear-gradient(-225deg, #A8BFFF 0%, #c15cbe 100%);
    border-radius: 10px;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    box-shadow: 0 4px 5px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2),
    0 7px 10px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14),
    0 2px 16px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
}...
```

Comment: Have you tried adding a webpack rule for `*.scss` files with `css-loader` and `sass-loader` inside?

Comment: Yes, but then a lot of errors come up.
*Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):

<template>
                                                                                                     ^
      Expected "{".
  ╷
1 │ exports = module.exports = require("../../../../../../node_modules/css-loader/lib/css-base.js")(false);
  │                                                                                                       ^
*

Comment: I can’t understand what I need to do. When I created a new project using vue-cli, everything was fine, because it was configured automatically, but how can I configure the scss module in laravel project - I can not find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

**At the moment, I made the modular scss work, but regular scss has stopped working. "scoped" - including.**

*webpack.mix.js*

```
mix.extend('rewriteRules', webpackConfig => {
let scssRule = webpackConfig.module.rules.find(rule => String(rule.test) === '/\\.scss$/');

scssRule.loaders[1] = { /* css-loader */
    loader: 'css-loader',
    options: {
        modules: true,
        importLoaders: 1,
        localIdentName: '[name]_[local]_[hash:base64:4]'
    }
};
});

mix.rewriteRules();
```

> If someone helps restore the operation of a non-modular sass, I would be grateful.